# CSS3 Character Encoding Declaration

Tags: css

Is character encoding declaration necessary to use in CSS3. And when I use the @charset "utf-8"; declaration it gives a warning in Visual Studio CSS3 validation. Can someone give a suggestion Please...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary but it is recommended if you have any non-ASCII text in your CSS file.

From http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php#atcharset:

```
@charset "<IANA-defined-charset-name>";
```

> Only one @charset rule may appear in an external style sheet and it must appear at the very start of the document. It must not be preceded by any characters, not even comments. (However, a byte-order mark is OK for a document in one of the Unicode encodings.)

Additionally you can try changing "utf-8" to uppercase, since it is defined uppercase by IANA: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml